# startActivityForResult triggers TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN thinking it went to the background

Tags: android, android-activity, application-lifecycle

How do I prevent using startActivityForResult in an activity from thinking it went to the background in the ApplicationLifecycleHandler?

Comment: Are you starting one of your activities, or an activity from a third-party app?

Comment: @CommonsWare it opens an activity to select your image so i guess a 3rd party app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `startActivityForResult()`, and it is starting up an activity that is not yours, then your app *is* moving to the background, and so the `TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN` value is correct.

Comment: How should i go about making an exception for the image picker?

Comment: @TimNuwin: It may be that the correct answer is for you to switch to `TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND` instead of `TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN` all the time. If you're sure that you normally want to use `TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN`, then you'll have to use a flag (set in `startActivityForResult()`, cleared in `onActivityResult()`) indicating that this third-party activity was launched, so you change your `onTrimMemory()` algorithm to accommodate that. However, bear in mind that the user might switch to something else entirely after you launch the image picker.